# Making first item only on the expandableListView enabled and the rest disabled

Tags: android

I have an expandable list view, I  was wondering if there is a way to make first the group item only enabled and expandable and the rest of the list disabled (user can't click it and expand it).

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: as per my understanding you have to require at a time one parentview expand am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Hi change in parent group view method in expandable list adapter

```
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_parent, viewGroup,
                        false);
            }

            ImageView img_parent_left = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_parent_left);
            ImageView img_parent_right = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_parent_right);
            if (i == 0) {
                img_parent_right.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                img_parent_left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
                if(i==0){
            ExpandableListView eLV = (ExpandableListView) viewGroup;
            eLV.expandGroup(i);
                }
            return convertView;
        }
```